# Short way to include CSS and javascript tags with HAML

Tags: ruby, haml

When including javascript or CSS in HAML you would normally have to do the following to include CSS:

```
%link{:type => "text/css", :rel => "stylesheet", :href => "/css/mycss.css"}
```

And for javascript:

```
%script{:type => "text/javascript", :src => "/js/myscript.js"}
```

I was wondering if HAML does not have a short way of including these tags (to get content from a source of course, not inline), that omits the need for the `type` and `rel` attributes, since these are invariable anyway.

Note that Ruby on Rails provides this feature via a function, but I'm not using rails.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't need the script's `type` attribute, and you can use the html syntax

```
%script(src="/js/myscript.js")
```

you could always create a "helper" to generate it if you feel like it

Answer (score 1):

I think what Ven was talking about might be something like...

```
# For CSS files...
def styletag(:sheet_name)
  "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/styles/#{:sheet_name}.css'>"
end

# For js files...
def jstag(:script_name)
  "<script src='/js/#{:script_name}.js'></script>"
end
```

Then, in your template, you can use them something like this:

```
- styletag "mystyles"
- jstag "myscript"
```